# How to create a custom bindable View in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Say, I want to have an `ObservableCollection<SomeModel>` to which will correspond a horizontal scrollable list of buttons. How can I do that?

Currently, I'm using the following code, but the problem is that it doesn't fit into MVVM model since, first of all, it lacks binding.

```
foreach (var item in result.Items)
{
    var button = new Button
    {
        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Button)),
        HeightRequest = 50,
        WidthRequest = 80,
        Text = item.Id,
    };

    _itemButtons.Add(button);

    var frame = new Frame
    {
        Content = button,
        Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10)
    };

    button.Clicked += OnItemClicked;
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => buttonsStack.Children.Add(frame));
}
```

If list should have been vertical, I would certainly use a ListView, but since it shouldn't (and there is no "normal" way of making ListView horizontal, rotating it and then rotating every item in it feels just wrong), I can't.

I want to have several buttons aligned in a row (I obviously don't know their number in the beginning) like following:

[image]

When the user clicks on of the buttons, the rest of the buttons' opacities are set to 0.3 and they become less visible, thus creating the illusion that the button clicked is the selected option of some kind.

Comment: May we know what are you trying to achive ? like a use case with some drawings so maybe we could give you some other suggestions ? 
In my optionion , scrolling horizontally is an awekward experience , even when we are talking about PCs . So having horizontal scrolling is even worse experience in Phones (with the exception of CarouselView).
Anyways, there are some horizontal listview around (dont know if they support horizontal scrolling though)

Comment: see the edit please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only seeing the code you posted, in my view, what you are doing seems perfectly fine since your code-behind page is only messing with UI elements in regards to your collection of `Button`s. So there is no reason to move the collection of UI elements to a ViewModel.

I would suggest that when ever you want to add a button, do exactly like you are doing by calling `Add()` on the `buttonStack` children and when you want to remove a `Button`, get a reference to it and call `Remove()` on the `buttonStack` children.

Also, if you want horizontal scrolling action, just put your `buttonStack` in a `ScrollView` and set `ScrollView.Orientation` to `ScrollOrientation.Horizontal`.

If I missed the point of your questions, definitely let me know.

Comment: Shouldn't the information about which button is selected be stpred in ViewModel?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze It certainly could be. I think you are hitting on a debate around MVVM fanatics vs people who are less fanatical about it. In my opinion, since the buttons are UI elements and do not represent actual data, I would store them in the code-behind, if that made sense in my app. I would simply have a `private` class level `Button` variable to store the selected `Button`.